# Threadstatic lazy

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm curious if the following example code is thread-safe:

```
public class Test
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Foo current;

    public static Foo GetFoo()
    {
        return current ?? (current = new Foo());
    }
}

public class Foo
{
}
```

Normally, I would use `Lazy<T>` , but since there's a separate variable per single thread, the property should be inherently thread-safe, is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) clearly answers your question `A static field marked with ThreadStaticAttribute is not shared between threads. Each executing thread has a separate instance of the field, and independently sets and gets values for that field. If the field is accessed on a different thread, it will contain a different value.`, so good practice - work out yourself at least documentation, if stuck - ask for community help

Comment: The short answer is yes, this is completely thread-safe. Every thread that calls `GetFoo()` will get its own `Foo` singleton, lazily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you provide looks perfectly thread safe. If you are comfortable with `Lazy<T>` you could use `ThreadLocal<T>` which works in a similar fashion, but stores its value thread safe and per thread.

```
// Thread-Local variable that yields a name for a thread
ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
{
    return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
});
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Right, but If .NET is >=4.x

Comment: You should use ... **because** ...?

Comment: Good point. My 'answer' is more like a suggestion than an answer to the question.

Comment: @Ivan while I see your point the implied "because it does what you want with the least amount of custom code" seemed fine to me.

Comment: @Voo The comment was on the original answer. As I see, it has been improved after that and now is much better. Still not quite convinced why is using a class, delegate and whoever knows what inside  is better than the crystal clear original code, but anyway.

Comment: @Ivan and I checked the original answer before making my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The code is indeed `Thread`-safe but keep that in mind that ***each `Thread` is going to have its own instance***, which means, in Singleton for example, that you should not want to use [`ThreadStaticAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

The more useful usage that I have found for this attribute, is making not `Thread`-safe classes `Thread`-safe - like `Random` for example.

`Random.Next` might return `0` if being called from multiple `Threads`, making it `ThreadStatic` makes the instances different for each `Thread`.

On the other hand, `ThreadStatic` does not automatically initialize the field for each `Thread`.

[`ThreadLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx) on the other hand, allows you to provide an initialization method which is used like `Lazy<T>` and initializes stuff for you on the first access on each `Thread`.

***Note that `ThreadLocal<T>` will require you to access the actual data through its `Value` property.***

Also, your initialization is in the `GetFoo` method anyway, so every instance will be initialized properly with `ThreadStatic` too.